# Unable to convert date time in Laravel Carbon

Tags: laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have a date time field in my view which contains the date time in `dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A` format so what I want to change this format to default one when I save the record, so I have done this;

```
$enable_test = new EnableTest;
$enable_test->test_end_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A', $request->due_date)->toDateTimeString();
```

But this error coming:

**Unexpected data found.
↵Unexpected data found.
↵Unexpected data found.
↵The format separator does not match
↵A four digit year could not be found
↵Data missing**

Comment: Can you show us an example of the sort of date string you're sending? (Preferably by printing out `$request->due_date`, to rule out issues with misspelled form fields etc.)

Comment: `Monday, February 25th 2019, 2:06 AM` this the format I'm getting from the request.

Answer (score 1):

[Per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), the format:

```
Monday, February 25th 2019, 2:06 AM
```

corresponds to:

```
l, F jS Y, g:i A
```

not the `dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A` you've got in your code (which appears to be from JavaScript; the two languages don't use the same parameters for date formats).